# Can I create a full page in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

My host does not allow to publish code with javascript and I would like to know if it is possible to use GTM for this. In this case I will create a static page with a div and check the ID in GTM, if true I will run the script.

```
if (document.getElementById("id")) {

    // the script here
}
```

Does this idea make sense?

I'm asking before testing, because the page in this case is an e-commerce, and every time I publish a new version in GTM the performance drops drastically.

Comment: If your provider does not allow code with Javascript then you cannot use GTM, which is written in Javascript.

Comment: @eike-pierstorff GTM is enabled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but is considered a bad practice, according to a deleted comment, the scripts need to run after full loaded page.

Something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

   if (document.getElementById("id")) {    
       // the script here
   }

}, false);
```

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer, because it at least explains what would be the best method to do this. I'm not here to discuss what's right and wrong, I'm here to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes (from question and comment I gather that this is some sort of page editor that does not allow to include custom JS, but provides GTM access; if you were flat out not allowed to use JS, GTM would not work, either).

Good idea? No, for at least three reasons:

- This is not performant at all, since each bit of custom script will be eval'd (unless you use custom templates, but those cannot add things to the DOM).
- It is not super easy to maintain (YMMV), since you would need to add tags for your content and then update the tags with your links and navigation (conceivably you could automate this via the GTM API)
- You would be relying on free infrastructure with no Service Level Agreements for a business critical function, which is not a great idea.

It would probably be easier to change hosts (and/or use some server-side  technology to generate the website for you).

Comment: Thanks for your response. This page is a specific custom product page. The host provides a good backend for templates, but it's too complex for a beginner. I designed this page almost as a hobby. The platform update disabled the java script and if I refresh the page I think it's gone. If you can, look at the page, thank you: www.owlsports.com.br/garage